# Grub not showing, i've tried everything

Tags: grub2, grub-efi

i just installed a dual-boot with windows 10 and ubuntu, but instead of grub it just boots straight into ubuntu i've already disabled the hidden timeout, and the bios boots into grubx64.efi

Comment: What brand/model system? Do you have good backups? Please copy & paste the pastebin link to the BootInfo summary report ( do not post report), do not run the auto fix till reviewed. Use often updated ppa version over somewhat older ISO with your USB installer  or any working install.
https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair & 
https://sourceforge.net/p/boot-repair/home/Home/

Comment: Let it boot into Ubuntu. Then run *sudo update-grub*. Is Windows shown as being picked up in the output?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Unable to boot into Windows after installing Ubuntu, how to fix?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/217904/unable-to-boot-into-windows-after-installing-ubuntu-how-to-fix)